# How to test Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration connection?

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle12c

I was trying to install both Oracle instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0 and instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0

I am getting the following error then testing the ODBC driver configuration:

[image]

My `tnsnames.ora` file has:

```
UASERVER=
 (DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS_LIST=
   (ADDRESS=
    (COMMUNITY=TCP)
    (PROTOCOL=TCP)
    (HOST=10.3.240.40)
    (PORT=1521)
   )
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=RPA-DEV))
 )
```

Could anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: I don't think `KPI SERVER` is possible. The TNS must not contain spaces (as far as I know, at least it does not make sense).

Comment: I changed the TNS Service Name in to UASERVER. And again i got the error which is mentioned in the above question it self.

Comment: Here is the content which is in tnsnames.ora file

UASERVER=
 (DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS_LIST=
   (ADDRESS= 
    (COMMUNITY=TCP)
    (PROTOCOL=TCP)
    (HOST=10.3.240.40)
    (PORT=1521)
   )
  )
 (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=RPA-DEV))
 )

Comment: Do you have a database running on 10.3.240.40, and is it registered to the listener on port 1521 with service name `RPA-DEV`? You can run `lsnrctl services` on that host to check the valid/registered service names.

Answer (score 0):

Punya, the message indicates the service name is wrong so if you have the correct port specified I suspect the service name needs a dot extension. Does the sqlnet.ora file provide a default domain?  As Alex suggested you should check to see what the target listener is listening for via a status command.